# Error:Plugin with id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' not found

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle, build

I'm using this library in my Android app. (https://github.com/yazeed44/MultiImagePicker)

Before now, I was adding it to my project this way:

```
compile 'net.yazeed44.imagepicker:imagepicker:1.3.0'
```

The problem with importing it that way is, as far as I know, that I can't override any code because I'll lose all the changes after building the project again. (I need to change some code)

For that reason, I have downloaded the source code and I've imported the project as a module with this name: 'imagepicker'

After that, I added this line to my app build.gradle:

```
compile project(':imagepicker')
```

and this to my settings.gradle (Android Studio did it)

```
include ':app', ':imagepicker'
```

After doing that, I try to run the project and Android studio shows this error:

```
Gradle 'Project' project refresh failed
Error:Plugin with id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' not found.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you are using the module locally **you have to add in your top-level** `build.gradle` or in the `imagepicker/build.gradle` same config added in the imagepicker [build.gradle project](https://github.com/yazeed44/MultiImagePicker/blob/master/build.gradle).

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {

        //ADD THESE DEPENDENCIES
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.2'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
    }
}
```

An alternative can be modify the `imagepicker/build.gradle` **removing** the last 2 lines. But you have to test this way.

```
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/installv1.gradle'
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/bintrayv1.gradle'
```

If you check these files you will find the

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
```

In your case you don't need these files because they are useful only to uplaod in a maven repo the aar file.

Comment: After adding those dependencies, that error has disappeared, but now appears this one: Error:(63, 13) Failed to resolve: com.commonsware.cwac:cam2:0.2.3

Comment: I added this to imagepicker build.gradle and solved the problem:  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com"
    }
}

Answer (score 6):

I added below code in Project:gradle.build file and its resolved the problem :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com"
        }
    }
   }
```

**EDIT**

If you still facing after adding above maven dependencies
Change `url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com"` to `url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"`.

Comment: This is working for v1.3.0 but didn't work for v1.3.1 for me.

Comment: As @ChintanShah said i can solved my problem by v1.3.0